# CSS3 Hero Image: Whats the best pixel dimension and Image Size for a full screen responsive background?

Tags: image, css, background, size, dimensions

CSS3 Hero Image question:

Whats the best pixel dimension and Image Size for a full screen responsive background?

Whenever I use the cover property, it always seems to miss out most the image.

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: Basically a term used by web designers for a large banner image, in my case a full size image background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used photoshop to crop the image to a 16:9 ratio, 1920 x 1080 pixel dimension for best image quality. Seems to work well with my website, hopefully the file size (507kb) won't be an issue on page loading response times.

Answer (score 1):

Also, consider **running your images through a compressor**, which can greatly reduce their file size.

https://compressor.io